# R using temporary options settings inside a function

Tags: r, function

I have a function which requires that I set an option, namely `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. My all-too common approach was to store the existing value at the onset of the function

```
op <- option("stringsAsFactors")
```

and before calling `return(x)` make sure to call

```
options(op)
```

While that works, it's a lengthy and complex function that can return from several places, so I need to either make sure every `return(x)`  is preceded by `options(op)`, or create a tiny function (itself inside my function) that does only that:

`returnfunc <- function(x) {
   options(op)
   return(x) 
}`

So my question is: what would be a better way to do that? Specefically, one that would prevent that the function exits with an error and leave the parameter (unduly) modified?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a built in `on.exit` function that does exactly this. For example

```
f<-function() {
    op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    on.exit(options(op))

    read.table(...)
}
```

You can change what ever options you want in the `options()` call and it returns all the values before the changes as list so it's easy to reset. You can pass whatever expression you want to `on.exit`, here we just set the options back to what they were. This will run when ever the function exits. See `?on.exit` for more info.

Comment: Is it correct to say that op <- options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) is a deceptively sophisticated operation that does *two* things: i) stores the current option in `op`, AND updates the new option?

Comment: @stevec Yes. That line is doing to things, both documented in the `?options` help page. Passing a named parameter sets a new option value, but the function itself will return the previous option value which we store here as `op` so we can reset things when we are done. (Of course now with R4.0 the default value of stringsAsFactors has changed to FALSE. )

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a default argument that allows the user to change it if they wish, and then pass the argument into the function that uses it.

For example,

```
f <- function(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) {

        read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)

}
```

This way, you can change it to `TRUE` if you want, and no `options()` are changed.  You really don't want to be messing around with `options()` inside of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I'd rather not mess around it but if I don't, I get an error I can't make sense of right now. So as a short-term workaround I'll go with MrFlick's solution and keep investigating when I have time!

Comment: Also worth a look are `getOption("stringsAsFactors")` and `default.stringsAsFactors()`

Comment: Yes there's a subtelty I didn't know about options being set to neither FALSE nor TRUE.